# select based on value of char array column - KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a table built like so:

```
tab: ([]col1:();col2:())
`tab insert (`testsym; "testchararr")
```

I now want to select the row where `col2` has the value `"testchararr"`. I have tried like so:

```
select from tab where col2 = "test"
```

but this always returns `'length` error.

How can I query based on the value of a char array? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "like" or an adverb. e.g.

```
q)select from tab where col2 like "testchararr"
col1    col2
---------------------
testsym "testchararr"

q)select from tab where col2~\:"testchararr"
col1    col2
---------------------
testsym "testchararr"

q)select from tab where col2 like "test"
col1 col2
---------

q)select from tab where col2~\:"test"
col1 col2
---------
```

I advise checking the speed of each method. For more examples of qsql like in use see:
http://www.timestored.com/b/forums/topic/string-functions-like-search-replace-regex/

Answer (score 1):

Have figured this one out:

I need to use `like` instead of `=`

i.e.

```
select from tab where col2 like "test"
```